# Javascript Roman Numeral conversion algorithm produces correct results but fails FreeCodeCamp automated test

Tags: javascript

I've been working through FreeCodeCamp's javascript course. I wrote the code below to convert a number to its roman numeral equivalent, and although when I run it and log it's result to the console and it produces the correct result for all the given test cases, FreeCodeCamp's automated tester claims it fails for every condition.

Here is the code:

```js
//Convert the given number into a roman numeral. All roman numerals answers should be provided in upper-case.

function convertToRoman() {
  //dropping arguments into vars with this cool approach
  let [num] = arguments;
  
  //we will process the provided number from the largest roman symbol down
  //to the smallest

  if (num == 0) {
    //we have reached the base case, so return what is in the romanesult var
    return romanResult;
  } else {
    //Starting with 1000's represented as M
    if (num >= 1000) {
      
      let cutOff = 1000;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "M");
      
    } else if (num >= 900) {
      let cutOff = 900;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "CM"); 
    } else if (num >= 500) {
      let cutOff = 500;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "D");
      
    } else if (num >= 400) {
      let cutOff = 400;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "CD");
      
    } else if (num >= 100) {
      let cutOff = 100;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "C");
      
    } else if (num >= 90) {
      let cutOff = 90;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "XC");
      
    } else if (num >= 50) {
      let cutOff = 50;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "L");
      
    } else if (num >= 40) {
      let cutOff = 40;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "XL");
      
    } else if (num >= 10) {
      let cutOff = 10;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "X");
      
    } else if (num >= 9) {
      let cutOff = 9;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "IX");
      
    } else if (num >= 5) {
      let cutOff = 5;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "V");
      
    } else if (num >= 4) {
      let cutOff = 4;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "IV");
      
    } else if (num >= 1) {
      let cutOff = 1;
      let result = num / cutOff;
      conversion(num, cutOff, result, "I");
      
    }
    
  }

  return romanResult;
}

function conversion() {   //accept the details and convert to the actual roman numeral

  const [num, cutOff, result, romNum] = arguments;
      
      //let result = num / cutOff;
      let stem = Math.trunc(result);

      let romConverted = "";
      //let romNum = "D"
      //use the result to generate the loop

      for (let i = stem; i > 0; i--) {

        romConverted += romNum
      }

      romanResult += romConverted; 
      let remainder = result - stem;
      if (remainder > 0) {

        //sending remainder recursively
        convertToRoman(num - (stem * cutOff), romanResult);
      } else {

      }
}

let romanResult = "";
console.log(convertToRoman(16));
```

And here is the output from FreeCodeCamp claiming it failed the tests:

```
// running tests
convertToRoman(2) should return the string II.
convertToRoman(3) should return the string III.
convertToRoman(4) should return the string IV.
convertToRoman(5) should return the string V.
convertToRoman(9) should return the string IX.
convertToRoman(12) should return the string XII.
convertToRoman(16) should return the string XVI.
convertToRoman(29) should return the string XXIX.
convertToRoman(44) should return the string XLIV.
convertToRoman(45) should return the string XLV.
convertToRoman(68) should return the string LXVIII
convertToRoman(83) should return the string LXXXIII
convertToRoman(97) should return the string XCVII
convertToRoman(99) should return the string XCIX
convertToRoman(400) should return the string CD
convertToRoman(500) should return the string D
convertToRoman(501) should return the string DI
convertToRoman(649) should return the string DCXLIX
convertToRoman(798) should return the string DCCXCVIII
convertToRoman(891) should return the string DCCCXCI
convertToRoman(1000) should return the string M
convertToRoman(1004) should return the string MIV
convertToRoman(1006) should return the string MVI
convertToRoman(1023) should return the string MXXIII
convertToRoman(2014) should return the string MMXIV
convertToRoman(3999) should return the string MMMCMXCIX
// tests completed
// console output
XVI
```

But as mentioned above my code produces the correct result for all those conditions.

Comment: Your code relies on the variable `romanResult` declared in the global context which won't exist in the freeCodeCamp environment. It's set as a side effect in `conversion()`. This is poor practice. Ideally your functions should accept parameters and return a result. Rework your code so that `convertToRoman()` handles this variable internally, and passes it to `conversion()` so that a global is not required.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ended up rewriting it to put the table of roman numerals into an object and then looping over it instead of calling a function recursively. I'll probably also do another version passing parameters as you suggested for the practice of it.